# jQuery get similar function that returns $object

Tags: get, jquery

Is there a similar function to .get(), but instead of returning a DOM element it returns a jQuery Object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function. Is the same as `.get()` but returns a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a jQuery method that returns jQuery object with a specific index, as the get() method returns DOM element with a specific index?

Comment: You just do $('li') and get all <li> elements as jQuery objects, that's what you want or I'm getting it wrong?

Comment: I want jQuery object with a specific index. Index as a result of jQuery .index() method.

Answer (score 1):

You can query specific index of

by:

```
var idx = 1;
$('li:eq(' + idx +')')
```

or

```
var idx = 1;
$("li").eq(idx)
```